# CMU sphinx NameError: global name 'Ad' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, cmusphinx, nameerror

I've run the code before and got it running. A week later after a few package updates and installs i ran the code again. Now i'm getting this error message.

The code i used for this test:

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
for phrase in LiveSpeech(): print(phrase)

speech = LiveSpeech(lm=True, keyphrase='forward',kws_threshold=1e+20)

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase.segments(detailed=True))
```

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my/file/is/this.py", line 2, in <module>
    for phrase in LiveSpeech(): print(phrase)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.ad = Ad(self.audio_device, self.sampling_rate)
NameError: global name 'Ad' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, In the terminal I uninstalled using "sudo pip uninstall pocketsphinx". Then reinstalled it with "pip install pocketsphinx". This fixed the problem.